# Can I use the Settings Bundle editor in XCode to specify UIs other than those for Settings?

Tags: ios, uiview, plist, settings.bundle

The Settings Bundle editor in XCode (New->File->iOS->Resource->Settings Bundle) seems like a convenient tool for rapidly specifying a large range of user interfaces other than just user preferences.  Is there any way to use this tool and the `.plist` mechanism for declaratively specifying user interfaces in general, rather than just for user defaults?

In other words, can I create a settings bundle (but not for settings) and programmatically load it from my application bundle and have iOS generate a view (and controller?) from it within my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like [In App Settings Kit](http://inappsettingskit.com/).  This will let you make a settings page identical to the iphone one but inside your app.